# Deciphering redis logs

Tags: redis

In redis logs, a line related to background saves appears often, e.g.:

```
[11465] 06 Mar 08:10:11.292 * RDB: 541 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
```

Can anyone clarify what this line precisely means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When redis wants to save a snapshot, it does that by forking itself first and then the forked process saves the dataset, not disturbed by having to serve requests, etc.

Since you have two processes now, it could mean using twice as much RAM, right? But no, the operating systems actually optimize this scenario by having the new process refer memory pages of the old process.

Interesting thing happens when original server's memory changes after the fork (due to you issuing update commands or something). The forked process has to maintain whatever memory state it got when forked, so the system, before changing a shared page, **copies** the page to the forked process (so that it's no longer shared) and then changes original process' page. This is called "copy-on-write".

In your case, this roughly means that during time it needed for saving a snapshot, you changed 541MB of data.

Comment: Thanks for this Sergio. But one confusion: 541MB worth of data changes - does this mean the total space taken by the data *that changed* was 541MB? Or is there some other fat attached to it that inflates it to 541MB (e.g. data changed itself might be minuscule, but the memory pages on which this data resided add up to 541MB)? I'm having a hard time believing my app produced 541MB of data in two minutes! Today my Redis process was getting OOM killed, and I'm trying to figure out why (JICYI, related SO ques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692776/diagnosing-unexpected-redis-server-failure)

Comment: Btw, adding to this story, I did attempt to disable transparent huge pages a couple of days ago too.

Comment: @HassanBaig: yes, I meant 541 mb of ram pages. You change one byte, but the whole page has to be copied.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what average page size is (or how one can calculate it in case it varies)?

Comment: page size is a setting in your system, IIRC. Global and constant for all processes.