# Diagnosing unexpected redis-server failure

Tags: redis

One of my redis servers is repeatedly going down today without any overt, diagnosable cause. My users all end up getting `Error 111 connecting to unix socket: /var/run/redis/redis2.sock. Connection refused` errors.

Looking into the logs at `/var/log/redis`, the last few lines capture nothing more nefarious than a scheduled backup:

```
[8248] 09 Mar 07:48:17.090 * 10 changes in 21600 seconds. Saving...
[8248] 09 Mar 07:48:17.374 * Background saving started by pid 47613
[47613] 09 Mar 07:51:02.257 * DB saved on disk
[47613] 09 Mar 07:51:02.486 * RDB: 526 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[8248] 09 Mar 07:51:02.920 * Background saving terminated with success
```

The pid file still exists too. Which implies the server wasn't formally shut down, and redis was still daemonized?

I logged into my system and did `sudo service redis-server restart` twice to get it up and running. Apart from these logs, how else can I diagnose what might have gone wrong?

---

Update: I noticed that at the time of the first crash, disk swapping started taking place. This hasn't happened before. Moreover, `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` confirms swappiness is set to `2`.

`free -m` shows (after normal operation):

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         28136      27015       1120        305         80       6586
-/+ buffers/cache:      20349       7787
Swap:         1023        991         32
```

`free -m` shows (after the redis server goes down):

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         28136       8770      19365        305         60        441
-/+ buffers/cache:       8268      19868
Swap:         1023       1022          1
```

Comment: Did you look in the system log? I'm guessing that you've ran out of memory (did you remember to set Redis' `max-memory`?) and that the OS OOMed the process

Comment: Look in `/var/log/syslog` - `free` is not useful post-mortem

Comment: @ItamarHaber: Got it. Indeed I see the redis-server being OOM killed with log entries such as `kernel: [20863308.900611] Out of memory: Kill process 53291 (redis-server) score 414 or sacrifice child` and `kernel: [20863308.909021] Killed process 53291 (redis-server) total-vm:12388012kB, anon-rss:12352396kB, file-rss:0kB`. But howcome I seem to have enough memory when I check through `free -m`? What could be causing this? It's happening every hour or so.

Comment: Most likely reason is the persistence fork.

Comment: No need to disable these, they are irrelevant because of `appendonly no`.

Comment: Yes thought so. So then the only `fork()` that happens is one which relates to RDB snapshotting. My crashes haven't really tracked that schedule of snapshotting. Only 1 (out of 3) corresponded to an RDB snapshot. Is there any other reason for a `fork()` to be invoked?

Comment: No, no other reason. But 1 out 3 maybe explained by difference in load and COW. Anyway - set `maxmemory' :)

Comment: Gotcha. Although, how about setting up more swap space first - I predominantly use Redis as a DB and not cache. Secondly, if you want, you could just write everything in comments as an answer and I'll accept it. Conversely, I can write an answer myself too based on your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the work of the OS' OOM killer - you can verify/discredit the hypothesis by reviewing the `/var/log/syslog`.

In this case, the persistence job's overhead triggered the killer. You need to provision for that by setting `maxmemory` and allocating enough RAM to accommodate persistence's requirements, including COW.

Note that `free` isn't useful after the fact - you need to monitor your resources continuously.

As for swap, if you don't care about latency then you can certainly do that.